# Why is my program not dividing even numbers by two?

Tags: c, for-loop

It should scan 10 int numbers and then display them backwards, dividing the even ones by two, but it just displays them without dividing.

es:
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ==> 1 2 3 2 5 3 7 4 9 5
but mine does:
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ==> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
            a[i] = a[i] / 2; i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }

    for(int i = 9; i > -1; i--)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The middle loop incorrectly increments `i` twice per iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // <<== One increment
    if (a[i]%2 == 0 ) {
        a[i] = a[i]/2; i++;    // <<== Another increment - first branch
    }
    else
        i++;                   // <<== Another increment - second branch
}
```

In your case, all even numbers happen to be stored at even positions that your loop skips.

**Note:** A better solution is to drop the middle loop altogether, and do the division at the time of printing.

Answer (score 2):

The body of your second `for` loop advances `i`. Since it's also advanced in the loop's clause, it's advanced **twice**, effectively skipping any other element. Remove those advancements, and you should be OK:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)  {
        a[i] /= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, hope i will get better and help the community instead of asking stupid question like this. But thanks again for how fast and clear you explained to me. have a good day you all :)

Answer (score 1):

In your program you incrementing the for loop variable i two times inside the loop and loop also increment the value one time so the values are skipped that is the reason you are getting wrong output.herewith i have attached the corrected program and its output.hope you understand the concept .Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
 {
   int a[10];
   printf("\n Given Values are");
   printf("\n-----------------");

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
     {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0 ) 
          {
           a[i] = a[i] / 2;

           }
      }
  printf("\n After dividing the even numbers by 2 and print in reverse  order");
  printf("\n ----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--)
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Given Values are                                                                                                                                                                            
-----------------                                                                                                                                                                            
1                                                                                                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                                                                                                            
6                                                                                                                                                                                            
7    
8                                                                                                                                                                                            
9                                                                                                                                                                                            
10                                                                                                                                                                                           

After dividing the even numbers by 2 and print in reverse order                                                                                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------
5                                                                                                                           
9                                                                                                                                                                                            
4                                                                                                                                                                                            
7      
3                                                                                                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                                                                                            
1
```